# Automate the process of Pig, Hive, Sqoop

Tags: hive, mapreduce, apache-pig, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

I have data in **HDFS**(Azure **HDInsight**) in **csv** format. I am using **Pig** to **process** this Data. After processing in **Pig** the **Summarize** data will be stored in Hive. And then **Hive** table is exported in RDBMS using **Sqoop**. Now I need to **automate** all this process. Is this possible that I will write particular method for all these 3 task in **MapReduce**, then run this **MapReduce** job, and all these task execute one by one.
​For create MapReduce job , I want to use .**Net** **SDK**. So my question is this possible, and if **YES** than suggest some steps and **reference** **link** for this Question.
​Thank You.

Comment: don't know .Net SDK but you can all those things with Oozie workflow by running pig / hive & ect' action - let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thanks for reply. It will really help me.
​By mistake I wrote MapReduce Job, I should have to use HiveJob, PigJob, SqoopJob.
​Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run those task periodically I would recommend using [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/). Check out existing [example](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_Examples.html) and it have fairly good documentation

If you don't have this framework on your cloud, you can write your own MR, but I you have Oozie you can write DAG flow where each action on the graph can be pig/bash/hive/hdfs and more.

It can run every X day/hours/min and can email you in case of failure